# I can ping but Putty SSH says: server unexpectedly closed network connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssh, port, putty

I have a strange issue with a server (hosted in AWS). **I can ping from** the laptop of my office and it seems that I can also connect on port 22 with telnet like this:

```
$ telnet 10.151.127.4 22
```

output of telnet:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
```

But If i try to connect with Putty I recieve the following message as soon as I try to click Open:

> server unexpectedly closed network connection

Note that other collegues located in other sites can connect to it.

Note2: I can ping to it

Edit: solved, i updated my Putty version

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [su].

Answer (score -2):

USE ' terminator ' terminal instead of putty ,  or another vt100 support terminal to connect to the server , i encounter with the same issue and i fixed it by using the terminator. In my case the server was having bit older unix version , which needs vt100 supporting terminal to connect.

Comment: windows download link ? BTW from the answer of telnet it seems that the version is not old: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1

Comment: oops ,, didnt know you are using windows , i answered with my linux knowledge , i think you can use teraterm or secureSSH on windows

Comment: Please note that other collegues with putty can connect to it

Comment: so the issue could be the on the network end , did you check with security guyz with network monitoring at the time of you are connecting to server , that could be the most prominent action to trace the issue you are experiencing right now..